# Django LocaleMiddleware redirect не работает

Tags: django, nginx, docker, gunicorn

На локальной машине или в debug true на боевой машине при запросе на условный site.ai/ переходит автоматический редирект на site.ai/ru/ или, например, при site.ai/home/ на site.ai/ru/home. Но в debug false редирект не происходит, но nginx передает Accept-Language $http_accept_language. В чем может быть дело, куда копать?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
    "debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware",
]
```

nginx

```
upstream botto_django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name servername;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name sitename;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/botto.ai/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/botto.ai/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://botto_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Language $http_accept_language;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/media/;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/static/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    client_max_body_size 64M;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
}
```